# Improvements to Minkowski's second theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, convex-geometry, lattices

Let $L$ be a (full rank) lattice in $\mathbb{R}^t$ and let $K$ be a convex body. Minkowski's second theorem states that
$$
\frac{2^t}{t!} \det(L) \leq \lambda_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot \lambda_t \text{Vol}(K) \leq 2^t \det(L),
$$
where $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_t$ denote the successive minima of $L$ with respect to $K$.

Minkowski's second theorem is known to be best possible even when one fixes the lattice. However, I do not know what is the situation when one fixes the convex body instead.

I am particularly interested in the following special situation. Let
$$
K := \{ (x_1, \ldots, x_t) \in \mathbb{R}^t : |x_1| + \ldots + |x_t| \leq 1 \}
$$
and let $L$ be a sublattice of $\mathbb{Z}^t$. Are there any improvements to the upper bound of Minkowski's second theorem available in this case?

Comment: What kind of an answer are you looking for? The behavior of a random lattice? The measure of the lattices that satisfy a better bound?

Comment: I would be by far the most interested in a better bound for every sublattice $L$ of $\mathbb{Z}^t$ (i.e. a lower bound for $\text{inf}_{L \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^t} \frac{2^t \det(L)}{\lambda_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot \lambda_t \cdot \text{Vol}(K)}$), but I would also be happy to hear about other things known about this problem.

Comment: Note that $K$ is the unit ball of the $\ell_1$ norm. Minkowski's **first** theorem is known to be within an $O(\log n)$ factor of tight for the $\ell_1$ norm, see [Ducas and Pierrot](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/146.pdf). Their tight result is even effective in a strong sense --- one can solve bounded-distance decoding up to their bound efficiently on the explicit lattice they give which has large $\lambda_1(L)$ in the $\ell_1$ norm.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent reference. I would love to know if there is also a $\Omega(\log n)$ result (or some other function) of this type.